# Does the garbage collector collect an instance of a class that doesn't have a decorator when the component is destroyed in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I was faced with the situation of a memory leak and I could not decide whether there is really a memory leak.

I created a new instance of a class that doesn't have a decorator in component and when I destroyed the component, I doubted whether this instance was disposed of or not, and I made the following test.

```
//Class without the decorator
    export class SignalRService 
    {
    
        protected hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
        private url: string;
        public disconnected$ = new Subject();
    
        public createHubConnection = (url: string, loginToken: () => string) => {
                this.url = url;
                this.loginToken = loginToken;
                this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.None)
                    .withUrl(this.url, {
                        skipNegotiation: true,
                        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
                        accessTokenFactory: this.loginToken
                    })
                    .build();
                this.hubConnection.onclose(() => {
                    this.disconnected$.next();
                });
                setInterval(() => {
                    console.log("************************");
                    console.log("signal service still alive:  " + this.url);
                    console.log("************************");
                }, 2000);
                return this;
            };  
    }

    @Component({
        selector: "page-one",
        templateUrl: "./page-one.component.html",
    }) 
    
    export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
        signalRService: SignalRService;
        paramModel: RequestModel = new RequestModel();
        
        constructor(
            private authService: AuthService,
        ) {}
        
        ngOnInit() {
            this.signalConfiguration(this.paramModel);
        }
        
        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.signalRService = null;
        }
        
        signalConfiguration(parameters: RequestModel) {
            if (this.signalRService) {
                this.signalRService = null;
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.signalRService = new SignalRService();
                this.signalRService
                    .createHubConnection(
                        this.config.serviceRealTime +
                            "/" +
                            srervicesApiControllerEnum.ONE,
                        () => this.authService.signalRHeaderValue
                    )   
            }, 10);
        }
    }
```

As a result, when the app runs, even if I am not on the page-one
the log is written with the correct **"this.url"** property to the console with increasing frequency as the page changes and comes back.

Here I was expecting **this.url** property to be undefined even if setInterval works. What point am I missing?

Comment: `this.url` is still being referenced in the interval so it wouldn't be disposed. Similar if you have other browser API events referencing variables in your components without cleaning them up when the component is destroyed.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen then, can we say, if we write a method to the signal service and clear all the intervals here and complete the subjects etc. Then, if we set signalService to null after calling this method from ngOnDestroy in the page-one component, it will be disposed. is it true?

Comment: If there are no references to the object in user code or through any of the browser APIs then the GC should collect it.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen thank you very much for your answers. If you want, you can write them as answers and I will accept them.